# What is the purpose of the ptrSafe attribute of a declare statement

Tags: vba, 32bit-64bit

In VBA, I need to `declare` a function in a DLL with the `ptrSafe` attribute if I am using it in a 64-bit Office environment.

As far as I can see, the `ptrSafe` does not technically change anything so that I am not sure what the purpose of the `ptrSafe` attribute actually is.

Comment: The `ptrSafe` means that the declaration can be executed on a 64bit platform. It doesn't really make the call safer. It appeared with the 64bit version of Excel as mean to prevent old code to run on a 64bit Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realistically, as far as I am concerned, the keyword serves no function other than **ensuring that old code will not compile in VBA7**.

> Existing Declare statements won't compile in 64-bit VBA until they've been marked as safe for 64-bit by using the PtrSafe attribute
>
> [Office Client Development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/shared/compatibility-between-the-32-bit-and-64-bit-versions-of-office#api-compatibility)

This having the impact that Microsoft Office could provide a standard error to users which try to run 32-bit code in VBA7 and force VBA developers to re-assess their code. If code was simply ran, it might cause a crash, which in some cases could happen on `Workbook_Open` or similarly "randomly".

Personally, I feel that introduction of the keyword is awful design, and contributes to the schism between VBA and VB6. The use of keyword `PtrSafe` provides no guarantees in reality, other than that the user has added the keyword. It does not guarantee they have checked for handles and converted those to `LongPtr`. And as a result of this bad design, we now need to use complex macros to compile code for both 64 and 32 bit office...

```
#if Win64 then
    Private Const NULL_PTR as LongLong = 0^
#else
    Private Const NULL_PTR as Long = 0&
#end if

#if VBA7 then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (Optional ByVal hWnd As LongPtr = NULL_PTR) As Long
    '...
#else
    Private Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (Optional ByVal hWnd As Long = NULL_PTR) As Long
    '...
#end if
```

No, instead, Microsoft would have been better:

1. Releasing a patch for 32-bit VBA and VB6 which adds the `LongPtr` type.
2. Kept old declare syntax as it was

If this were done, the following would suffice for both 32 and 64 bit systems:

```
Private Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (Optional ByVal hWnd As LongPtr = 0) As Long
```

And hell even if they didn't release a patch for 32-bit VBA/VB6 we could still use macros and an Enum:

```
#If VBA7 = 0 then
  Enum LongPtr
    [_]
  End Enum
#End If
Private Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (Optional ByVal hWnd As LongPtr = 0) As Long
'...
```

But alas, because of the introduction of this keyword we now have to define all our statements twice if we want to remain compatible:

```
#If VBA7 then
  Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (Optional ByVal hWnd As LongPtr = 0) As Long
  '...
#Else 
  Enum LongPtr
    [_]
  End Enum
  Private Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (Optional ByVal hWnd As LongPtr = 0) As Long
  '...
#End If
```

If I were Microsoft I'd make `PtrSafe` keyword optional. Doing so would do a world of good.

Answer (score 0):

`PtrSafe` serves to tell VBA that API declarations are safe: `Ptr (pointer)` `Safe (safe, safe)`

This attribute indicates that we target the 64-bit version.

**For Example**

Take the `ShellExecute` API function, which opens any file in its default application without knowing it. For example, an .xlsx document will open in Excel, a .pdf will open in Acrobat Reader, unless you have installed another PDF reader (such as Sumatra PDF).

The API declaration of this function has changed to `64-bit` version. To make `32 and 64-bit` versions coexist in the same database, write this:

```
' --- DECLARATION API WINDOWS
#If VBA7 Then
  Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShellExecute _
    Lib "shell32.dll" _
    Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
      ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpOperation As String, _
      ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, _
      ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) _
    As LongPtr
#Else
  Private Declare Function ShellExecute _
    Lib "shell32.dll" _
    Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
      ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, _
      ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, _
      ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) _
    As Long
#End If
```

[Original content can be found there](https://www.oipapio.com/question-16934448)

Comment: "The API declaration of this function has changed to 64-bit version" -- that's not really accurate. Using VBA7 syntax means that the declaration will run in both 32-bit or 64-bit version just fine. It just won't blow up because the `LongPtr` scales to either 32-bit or 64-bit integer, whereas `Long` nor `LongLong` won't scale based on the hardware. In fact, your example has the VBA7 version running for either 32-bit or 64-bit Office; only older VBA6 hosts (e.g. Office 2007 and prior) will run the 2nd, non-pointer-safe version because `LongPtr` doesn't exist there.

Comment: In reality this keyword provides no guarantee of safety. You have physically changed the declare statement's parameters, granting it safety. The keyword `PtrSafe` does squat.